# Cognos Analytics: Split variable into two by month

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

In Cognos Analytics I have a dataset containing rows with data (used disk space in MB), with each row being either February or June. Because I want to compare the two months, I want to create two new variables: one with the February data and one with the June data.
In the Query editor I've tried: count (MB) when month = 'February'. This, and a couple of other entries don't work.
I wonder if anyone can provide me the right line of code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please support the code that did not work and the table description.

Comment: `count (MB) when month = 'February'` will not work as the expression for a data item in Cognos Analytics.  If you didn't get an error message, are you sure you're using Cognos Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Go to query explorer
- Create a query for each month
- Join the 2 queries (this will result in 3rd query)

At this point you should be able to handle each month as a separate data item

[image]

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your respons! I forgot to mention that I'm creating a dashboard, not a report. Do you know how to apply your solution in the dashboard module?

Comment: Would need more information on what your options are.  Do you have access to Framework Manager or ask them for changes to the model?  If not,  maybe the ability to create a data module?